# Symfony2 Doctrine insert/update form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I am trying to compose a very basic form which is capable of inserting and as well updating records in the database.
My problem is that each time I press the Save button, a new row is created in the DB.
Could you please point to the problem in my source code?

controller: http://pastebin.com/YjMAdHqp

routing: http://pastebin.com/WSV6xCSw

The id column in the database is an auto-increment integer.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer for your question is using merge method instead persist. e.g.:

```
$your_entity = $form->getData();
$this->em->merge($your_entity); // MERGE not PERSIST
$this->em->flush();
```

You can read more about Merge Method at the [official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities)

Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

```
  if ($id == 0) {
    $task = new Task();
  }
```

Your ID parameter defaults to 0 and a new Task is created instead of updating an existing tast.

```
hello_index:
    pattern: /hello/index/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:hello:index, id:0 }
```

You should seperate create and edit/update action and create a routing for each action.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object